# Appropriate arguments to copy data form HFS+ formatted drive to ZFS array

Tags: mac-osx, zfs, truenas, hfs+

I'm migrating away from Drobo. I have about 4TB of data on a Drobo 5D, which is connected to a Mac Mini and formatted with HFS+. I used [this command](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117465/fastest-and-safest-way-to-copy-massive-data-from-one-external-drive-to-another) to copy the data there originally:

> sudo rsync -vaE --progress /Volumes/SourceName /Volumes/DestinationName

I'm moving the data to FreeNAS, which uses ZFS. However, this command produced hundreds of thousands of errors when I tried to use it for this move, which I believe may be due to trying to copy extended attributes and resource forks.

What are appropriate arguments to copy data stored on HFS+ to a FreeNAS ZFS dataset? I only want to see a status summary and errors. I'll be running this command from a macOS Sierra Terminal Window.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following:

> sudo rsync -az -H /Volumes/SourceName /Volumes/DestinationName

-a archive mode

-z compress file data

-H preserve hard links

So far, there have been no errors like I had been seeing with my previous rsync arguments.

One completed (could take days) I'll verify the results and update my answer if necessary.

Comment: `-z` to rsync causes data to be compressed *during the transfer*. (Remember that even when executed locally, rsync uses a client/server architecture.) For local executions, typically *all* that specifying -z will do is to increase your CPU usage; if you are lucky, you have sufficient CPU cycles to spare that this doesn't slow down the copying overall. It's really only meaningful to add -z if you are network throughput bound and have plenty of CPU to spare on both ends that can be used for the compression and decompression respectively.

Comment: Actually, I found that using `-z` slowed down my transfer, or at least appeared to. So I ended up removing that argument.